# How to add relationship at the time of new user creation in drupal?

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

I want to add relationship (civicrm) at the time of creation of new user using drupal user. (individual -> Household).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Drupal rule to achieve this provided you have that functionality turned on.

Could use the 'Civicrm contact has been created' event.

Checkout the Drupal 7 rules module: https://www.drupal.org/project/rules
Civicrm comes with Civicrm rule intergration module which you can enabled (although you may not need to enable this).

Comment: How can you do that? Any reference online tutorial.

Comment: @DipakGiri You can lookup how the Drupal rules module works and then you can look at what you need to enabled to get that event.  I actually have that event provided withour the Civicrm rules module enabled so you may not even need to enable that.  I believe there is also extension for civi https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules

Comment: https://civicrm.org/blog/petednz/creating-drupal-users-made-easy-for-single-or-multiple-contacts-via-civi-imports-and